# Paging through API response is not returning all rows in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am using Power Bi to call an API and I want to page through the results.  Here is my code:

```
let
    url = "http://localhost/test,
    iteration = 10          

    getPage =
        (url, pageNo) =>
            let
                Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(url & "&page=" & Number.ToText(pageNo)), 65001),
                results = Source[results]
            in
                results,
    GeneratedList = 
        List.Generate(
            () => 
               [i=0, res = getPage(url,i)],
               each [i]<iterations and [res]<>null,
               each [i=[i]+1, res = getPage(url,i)],
               each [res])
        )
in
    GeneratedList
```

My problem is that I want to page through the API response and keep appending the "results" value in the getPage function above until I have been through all the pages.

The "results" JSON object is a simple list like this:

```
"results": [
        {
            "Id": "1234567890abcdef",
            "name": "Test"
        }]
```

The result I am seeing at the moment shows a list with an error entry and if I click on the list it then only shows 10 records with 10 being the record limit for each page so it looks like it is only returning 1 page.  There should be 215 records in total.

[image]

[image]

The API also does not return a total page value so I need to calculate this by dividing the totalPages in the API response by the recordlimit value in the API response.

So my questions are:

- How do I page through the API response and return only the "results" values appended together
- What is the best way to calculate the totalPages?  I have seen some solutions that do a call the API especially to get the totalPage information or do I recalculate it everytime in the getPages function or is there another way?

Thanks for any help

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: It just says error like in the screenshot.  I can't see any other information about it.  Is there a way to find out?

Comment: You've declared `iteration` but later referred to it as `iterations`. I also recommend testing the API outside of Power BI using a tool like curl to see what it returns both when you expect it to return something and when you don't.